# Access HTTP request headers from HTML or JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a situation that my DNS forwards a naked domain to my app like this:

```
http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com/index.html
```

This looks fine until client need to access subfolder through naked domain like:

```
http://mydomain.com/abc
```

And the still DNS forwards to `http://www.mydomain.com/index.html`

I'm sure I can get the `subfolder` (like 'abc') from the request headers within Javascript in the HTML and parse the `subfolder` from there right? Or I am mistaken.

Comment: There is no such header, at least it is not transmitted using a browser - just check request headers using e.g. Firebug. What kind of obscure setup are you talking about? Sure this is about DNS, or is it about a reverse proxy in front of your application?

Comment: subfolder should have a / after it.